# Change review status in TFS

Tags: tfs, tfs-code-review

We are using Visual Studio 2013 and TFS 2013.  I helped another team member develop some code which he sent out for a code review.  I added a comment to his code review.  Unfortunately I did not realize that adding a comment would automatically update me to accepted status.

Per our team policy I should not review this since I wrote some of the code being reviewed.  How can I change my status from accepted to declined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to decline after accepting. My suggestion would be to click the arrow beside Send & Finish and choose With Comments. Alternatively, you could simply not complete the code review (i.e., don't Send & Finish).

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on the best way to add comments to the review without accepting it?